# Diffing Binary Files In Python

Tags: python, diff

I've got two binary files.  They look something like this, but the data is more random:

File A:

```
FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF 44 43 42 41 FF FF ...
```

File B:

```
41 42 43 44 00 00 00 00 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 ...
```

What I'd like is to call something like:

```
>>> someDiffLib.diff(file_a_data, file_b_data)
```

And receive something like:

```
[Match(pos=4, length=4)]
```

Indicating that in both files the bytes at position 4 are the same for 4 bytes.  The sequence `44 43 42 41` would not match because they're not in the same positions in each file.

Is there a library that will do the diff for me?  Or should I just write the loops to do the comparison?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html - first result in google for "diff in python"

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between two strings in python/php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209800/difference-between-two-strings-in-python-php)

Comment: @Andrey thanks, I tried that, but it appears that `get_matching_blocks()` doesn't check if the bytes are in the same spot in each files, just that the sequence exists in each file.  Otherwise, yeah, that's pretty much what I want.

Comment: So you want to get a list of every position where a match starts and the length of that match, and you don't care about sections of the file that *would* match if they were lined up properly?

Comment: @KyleStrand yes, I think so.  Although I'm not sure what "lined up properly" would mean in this case.  In my example above, I do not want the `44 43 42 41` to match because they're in different positions; if that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean you're ignoring chunks of data that look the same if the starting indexes don't match.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yeah, in my case that's totally fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this, here is an example:

```
from itertools import groupby

# this just sets up some byte strings to use, Python 2.x version is below
# instead of this you would use f1 = open('some_file', 'rb').read()
f1 = bytes(int(b, 16) for b in 'FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF 44 43 42 41 FF FF'.split())
f2 = bytes(int(b, 16) for b in '41 42 43 44 00 00 00 00 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37'.split())

matches = []
for k, g in groupby(range(min(len(f1), len(f2))), key=lambda i: f1[i] == f2[i]):
    if k:
        pos = next(g)
        length = len(list(g)) + 1
        matches.append((pos, length))
```

Or the same thing as above using a list comprehension:

```
matches = [(next(g), len(list(g))+1)
           for k, g in groupby(range(min(len(f1), len(f2))), key=lambda i: f1[i] == f2[i])
               if k]
```

Here is the setup for the example if you are using Python 2.x:

```
f1 = ''.join(chr(int(b, 16)) for b in 'FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF 44 43 42 41 FF FF'.split())
f2 = ''.join(chr(int(b, 16)) for b in '41 42 43 44 00 00 00 00 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37'.split())
```

Comment: Hot.  I'm loving what you're doing there.  I was hoping for a beautiful answer like this.

Answer (score 3):

The provided `itertools.groupby` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15798718/2789762) works fine, but it's pretty slow.

I wrote a pretty naive attempt using `numpy` and tested it versus the other solution on a particular 16MB file I happened to have, and it was about 42x faster on my machine. Someone familiar with `numpy` could likely improve this significantly.

```
import numpy as np

def compare(path1, path2):
    x,y = np.fromfile(path1, np.int8), np.fromfile(path2, np.int8)
    length = min(x.size, y.size)
    x,y = x[:length], y[:length]

    z = np.where(x == y)[0]
    if(z.size == 0) : return z

    borders = np.append(np.insert(np.where(np.diff(z) != 1)[0] + 1, 0, 0), len(z))
    lengths = borders[1:] - borders[:-1]
    starts = z[borders[:-1]]
    return np.array([starts, lengths]).T
```