# Determine difference of 2 large binary files?

Tags: python, binary, difflib

I need to compare and get the difference of 2 large binary files (up to 100 MB).

For ASCII format I can use this:

```
import difflib
file1 = open('large1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('large2.txt', 'r')
diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
difference = ''.join(x[2:] for x in diff if x.startswith('- '))
print(difference)
```

How would one make it work for binary files? Tried different encoding, binary read mode but nothing worked yet.

EDIT: I use `.vcl` binary files.

Comment: You say that the files that you want to compare are binary files, but you treat them as if they were large text files. Can you clarify what type of data you're working with?

Comment: @Schmuddi these are .vcl type of files and contain data from an instrument.

Comment: and what is the usage case? you need the deltas for synchronization?if yes, perhaps the `librsync` wrapper would be practical - https://github.com/smartfile/python-librsync/

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798411/diffing-binary-files-in-python) has two answers that might be useful for comparing binary files.

Comment: @Schmuddi I will have a binary file updating in real time and after each 30 min I need to copy over the new updated data and send it to a server. My plan is to compare the files get the diff and send it each time.

Answer (score 2):

difflib will be extremely slow for large file, 100MB would be categorized as very large...

> Timing: The basic Ratcliff-Obershelp algorithm is cubic time in the worst case and quadratic time in the expected case. SequenceMatcher is **quadratic time for the worst case** and has expected-case behavior dependent in a complicated way on how many elements the sequences have in common; **best case time is linear**.

If you can tolerant the slowness, try `difflib.SequenceMatcher`, it works for almost all type of data.

> This is a flexible class for comparing pairs of sequences of any type, so long as the sequence elements are hashable.

[Pythone Doc - class difflib.SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher)